# login with Instagram private API

Tags: instagram

I would like to develop an Android app integrate with Instagram. I found that the official Instagram API not helping me very much so I discovered that there is a private API of Instagram that I can do all the actions that I want.

so i want to use Instagram Private API, but when i call `https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/feed/reels_tray/` or other APIs get the Following Response:

```
message "login_required"
logout_reason   4
status  "fail"
```

i have a `ds_user_id` and `sessionid` and send this parameter by request!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the API need login first.

most of https://i.instagram.com/api API, all need login.

this is not public API.

Answer (score 0):

Do a login first, store the session and then you can send other requests with the private api.

Login is required to make most of requests to the private API.

I recommend this API: https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API
You can see an easy example to get started here: https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API/blob/master/examples/accessingValues.php

Before you make any calls a correct/complete login needs to happen from the device.